# Android Studio Build Wear OS module not building

Tags: wear-os, google-play-console, android-wear-3.0

So. In my Android Studio project there is both an App for mobile and a module for wear OS. Debugging works perfect. The app can communicate with the wear app when i install it via androids debugging.
But when i try to build signed app bundles, there is only one aab file. Then yea the wear app might be included that, so i try to upload it to playstore, but the playstore doesnt seem to recognize the wear module and doesnt even show an option to add wear screenshots, as if theres no wear module.
I cant seem to find a solution for day. And there is so little discussion on Stackoverflow and other places about Wear OS

I tried to select the either app or wearapp for creating aab but either way it just made one.

Secondly the package names and build versions are the same.

Comment: Can you build both apps with separate gradle commands. There has to be two APKs/AABs.  You can't have a single one.